# Two components of angular momentum conserved $\Rightarrow $ All three components are conserved?

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, hamiltonian-formalism, poisson-brackets

I was wondering whether it is correct to say that if two components of the angular momentum are conserved, then all three Cartesian coordinates of the angular momentum are conserved? I would regard this as a direct consequence from the Poisson bracket. Is this correct so far?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Yes,* because $\{J_i,J_j\}_{PB}=\sum_{k=1}^3\epsilon_{ijk} J_k$. More generally, the statement that *the Poisson bracket of any two constants of motion is again a constant of motion* is known as *Poisson's Theorem.*